# Desplegar un arreglo de un documento de mongodb en html/jade

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, jade

Saludos, tengo un problema y es que no se como puedo consultar los elementos de un documento que tiene un arreglo y mostrarlos en Jade.

```
Recibo.aggregate(
{"$match":{"nombre":{"$in":req.body.listNombrePTC},"fecha":{"$gte": lastWeekDay, "$lte": today }}},
{"$group":{"_id": "$nombre", "recibos":{"$push": "$$ROOT"}}},function(error,docs){
        if(error) {throw error}
        console.log( JSON.stringify( docs, undefined, 2 ) );
        res.render("comprobacionGastos/listaSemanal",{listaRecibos: docs})
    }   
)
```

Cuando se ejecuta esa consulta, me devuelve documentos con un arreglo cada uno.

[image: Captura de pantalla]

Entonces, mi problema es, basicamente que no se como consultar esos arreglos en Jade para mostrarlos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pug (antes Jade) permite iterar mediante [`each`](https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html#each) y [`while`](https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html#while).

**Ejemplo**

```
ul
  each cliente in clientes
  li= cliente._id
  ul
    each recibo in cliente.recibos
    li= recibo._id
    li= recibo.nombre
    li= recibo.fecha
    li= recibo.gasto
    li= recibo.concepto
```

Se supone que `clientes` es el nombre de la llave del objeto que has pasado a renderizar:

```
let clientes = /* tu consulta */;
res.render('clientes_recibos', { clientes });
```

Comment: Buenas, estuve experimentando usando el nombre del arreglo como un atributo y empezo a poner la informacion del array.

  **td= Recibo.recibos[i].nombre**  

y empeze a  iterar con each como mencionaste arriba, ahora estoy acomodando los resultados para que salgan:

Nombre1 -> Datos
Nombre2 -> Datos
etc...

Comment: No entiendo, ¿solucionaste tu duda o aún no?

Comment: Si, ya resolvi la duda ahorita solo ando acomodando los datos para que se lean mejor, gracias :D

Comment: Genial. Me alegro se haya resuelto. Saludos.